# Forward slash and exponent causing a problem

Tags: spacing

The following lines

"If the density of gold is 19.3 tonnes/m^{3} and"

"If the density of gold is 19.3 tonnes\slash m^{3} and"

produces

If the density of gold is 19.3/m^3*and*

So that the cube is shown correctly but the subsequent text is one string and in italic.

I am a learner and don't know enough to be able to understand what has gone wrong.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although you haven't given much information (we request a small compilable example to allow potential helpers to copy and paste, to experiment), the likely cause of the problem is that the `^` requires math mode, which you haven't indicated.  TeX will try to recover by entering math mode, so everything following will be in math mode as well (where spaces are ignored, and letters are italic).  This will be reported in your log file; you should always check the log for problems.  Perhaps a bit of guidance is in order.  Try visiting https://www.learnlatex.org/

Comment: Thank you, that has helped me.

Comment: `\usepackage{siunitx}` and then `The density of gold is~\qty{19.3}{\tonne\per\meter\cubed}` ;-)

Comment: To type m³ in latex text without packages you can use `m$^3$` or `m\(^3\)` or `m\textsuperscript{3}`. The first two use the inline math mode to make the superscript, so be careful with the start and stop of that mode with  `$`, or better with  `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: Thanks, good to know

Comment: Thanks Rmano, I'm using your suggestion.